# SQL Server : error creating two foreign keys on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, normalization

```
create table TiposPeliculas
(
    id_tipoPelicula int identity (1, 1), 
    descipcion varchar (30)
    constraint pk_tipoPelicula primary key(id_tipoPelicula)
)

create table Generos
(
     id_genero int identity (1,1), 
     descripcion varchar(20)
     constraint pk_generos primary key(id_genero)
)

create table Peliculas 
(
     id_pelicula int not null, 
     id_tipoPelicula int, 
     id_genero int, 
     titulo varchar (30),
     duracion time,
     idioma varchar (30),
     sub bit
     constraint pk_pelicula primary key (id_pelicula, id_tipoPelicula)
     constraint fk_generoPelicula foreign key (id_genero) references Generos (id_genero),
     constraint fk_tipoPeliculasDePeli foreign key (id_tipoPelicula) references TipoPeliculas (id_tipoPelicula)
)
```

The FOREIGN KEY for `id_tipoPelicula` throws an error:

> foreign key "fk_tipoPeliculasDePeli" references invalid table "TipoPeliculas"

Comment: This looks like a Typo question: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Obviously if you stare at your code long enough, you'll notice there's a typo on your statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Peliculas 
(
      id_pelicula int not null, 
      id_tipoPelicula int, 
      id_genero int, 
      titulo varchar (30),
      duracion time,
      idioma varchar (30),
      sub bit 
  constraint pk_pelicula primary key (id_pelicula, id_tipoPelicula)  
  constraint fk_generoPelicula foreign key (id_genero) references Generos (id_genero), 
  constraint fk_tiposPeliculasDePeli foreign key (id_tiposPelicula) references TiposPeliculas (id_tiposPelicula)
)
```

This will work the error in spelling mistake in relation name TiposPeliculas.

Comment: not running, new error mss: "foreign key "fk_tiposPeliculasDePeli" references invalid column "id_tiposPelicula" in referencing table "Peliculas" "

Comment: I DID IT, thank for the help LUV, this is te table that ran:
create table Peliculas 
(id_pelicula int not null, id_tiposPelicula int, id_genero int, titulo varchar (30),duracion time,idioma varchar (30),sub bit
constraint pk_pelicula primary key (id_pelicula,id_tiposPelicula)
constraint fk_generoPelicula foreign key (id_genero) references Generos (id_genero),
constraint fk_tipoPeliculasDePeli foreign key (id_tiposPelicula) references TiposPeliculas (id_tipoPelicula))

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> foreign key "fk_tipoPeliculasDePeli" references invalid table "TipoPeliculas"

It says, the foreign key is reference to invalid Table "TipoPeliculas", Which means table "TipoPeliculas" doesn't exists.

In your question the table name is "TiposPeliculas". Hence it seems you need to correct table name in reference.

Also the column name should be "id_tipoPelicula" instead of "id_tiposPelicula" in reference.

Run the below code

```
create table TiposPeliculas
(
    id_tipoPelicula int identity (1, 1), 
    descipcion varchar (30)
    constraint pk_tipoPelicula primary key(id_tipoPelicula)
)

create table Generos
(
     id_genero int identity (1,1), 
     descripcion varchar(20)
     constraint pk_generos primary key(id_genero)
)

create table Peliculas 
(
     id_pelicula int not null, 
     id_tipoPelicula int, 
     id_genero int, 
     titulo varchar (30),
     duracion time,
     idioma varchar (30),
     sub bit
     constraint pk_pelicula primary key (id_pelicula, id_tipoPelicula)
     constraint fk_generoPelicula foreign key (id_genero) references Generos (id_genero),
     constraint fk_tipoPeliculasDePeli foreign key (id_tipoPelicula) references TiposPeliculas (id_tipoPelicula)
)
```